# How to read constant size buffers from a named pipe, and run a command for each buffer

Tags: shell-script, command-line, dd

There is a function in terminal: `redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel`. It reads data from `stdin` and does its job.

FIFO itself doesn't give chunked data. So I need to create chunks from the stream, and run `redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel` for each chunk.

I already tried this:
`{ while :; do dd iflag=fullblock iflag=nonblock bs=65536 count=1 2> /dev/null | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel ; done } < myFifo`

It's working. But is highly CPU consuming. And very bad for scaling (50 concurrent commands caused 40% CPU usage).

I also tried the solution provided by @terdon [[here]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458815/high-cpu-usage-with-while-loops-running-dd-command/1458823?noredirect=1#comment2552137_1458823):

```
{ 
  while :; do 
    dd iflag=fullblock iflag=nonblock bs=65536 count=1 2> /dev/null | 
      redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel 
    sleep 0.1
  done 
} < myFifo
```

It uses less CPU (20% for 50 concurrent commands). But still will cause problem in larger scale.

I also tried using `tail -F` to read from the FiFo [as suggested by @raffa](https://askubuntu.com/a/1458823/85695):

```
tail -c +1 -F myFifo | 
  dd iflag=fullblock bs=65536 2> /dev/null | 
    redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because `redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel` must run for each chunk. It can't receive a data stream.

Is there a way that can accomplish what that command does, but CPU efficient?
I might add, the solution needs to be working in **Ubuntu 16.04 and above**.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you use `split -b … --filter=…`? I mean: does your `split` support `--filter`? [Example](https://superuser.com/a/1679017/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure. Someone told me that `split` is in `coreutils` and is widely available in different Ubuntu versions. I can test it if you provide a command.

Comment: Why are you using nonblock?

Comment: @frostschutz Well I'm not a linux expert. So I tried what was looking right, based on my search. The combination of 'while' and 'dd' command causes the problem here. I also tried without `iflag=nonblock`. No difference.

Comment: you might want to remove the `2> /dev/null` to better see what happens

Comment: With nonblock there is a chance it runs for 0 byte. You can put `| tee somefile.$RANDOM |` after dd and see what data it passes through. if there are many 0 bytes files, that would waste tons of CPU for nothing. In the end all these solutions are inefficient, it would be better if redis itself had a way to process this data without building loops around it. Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with redis, so...

Comment: as far as I can see, `iflag=nonblock` makes GNU dd just do an error exit when it gets the inevitable EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, so here it would just make sure that turns into a busyloop. Without it, it should do much better. As long as the input pipe is open, that is, since you have no way to see detect when it closes to break the loop.

Comment: `<myFifo split -b 65536 --filter='redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel'` . This is not an answer because (1) I haven't tested and (2) I don't know how efficient it is.

Comment: @frostschutz Agreed. Redis publish can't get continuous stream unfortunately.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that looks fine based on a mock test, as long as the pipe stays open (it'll exit when it closes). I don't think efficiency can be much of an issue here, as long as one doesn't fall into busylooping over some failure condition.

Comment: @jameshofer, so, here's the question: how is that fifo being written to? what should happen if/when the writer to the pipe closes it?

Comment: Maybe redis-cli is just the wrong tool for the job? Not familiar with redis but SQLite has a similar issue. Performance is OK if you open the database once, then use it continuously. Performance is terrible if, for every single action, you re-open the database from scratch (new process per query). So maybe for redis this can be done more efficiently in a few lines of python or any other language that can work with redis in some way.

Comment: @frostschutz You're correct. I can do it in my NodeJS app. But while NodeJS is single threaded, it causes CPU heating in another way. It's complicated. Long story short, I decided to get that part out of my app, and leave it to Linux to handle it.

Comment: yes, of course it also depends on the frequence of the events, if you get a full block and need to start a new process thousands of times a second, that's going to hurt...

Comment: @ilkkachu It's a video stream. Writen by ffmpeg to named pipe. When ffmpeg exits, I kill the publisher. There's no problem with that part.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski it's working. And with 50 active commands used a small amount of CPU. So I think we can consider it as correct answer. The only thing that I worry about is that it can be used system wide in any ubuntu 16.04 and above.

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried this: `{ while :; do dd iflag=fullblock iflag=nonblock bs=65536 count=1 2> /dev/null | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myChannel ; done } < myFifo`
>
> It's working. But is highly CPU consuming. And very bad for scaling
> (50 concurrent commands caused 40% CPU usage).

`iflag=nonblock` asks the GNU coreutils dd to use non-blocking reads, meaning if there's no data to read, control returns back to the process immediately with error code EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, instead of having the OS handle waiting for more data. It looks like dd deals with that as it deals with any error, printing an error message and exiting. Because the loop just restarts dd, you get into the same situation again, and again, and again, in quick succession. Of course it causes high CPU usage.

If you hadn't redirected errors to `/dev/null`, you'd see output from dd like below, clearly showing how it runs repeatedly for a very short while at a time, doing nothing:

```
dd: error reading 'standard input': Resource temporarily unavailable
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 4.3734e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
[...]
```

Suggestions:

1) If you're testing something, or trying out for the best way to do something, *don't* hide errors, they can be quite useful.

2) If you're reading data and don't have anything else to do, just let the system call block.

Removing `iflag=nonblock` would go a long way in resolving that.

Also, I'm not sure you need dd there anyway, `head -c 65536` should do similarly.

---

But that still leaves what happens when the pipe you're reading from is closed. At that point, any reads will just (successfully) return zero bytes, indicating the end of the data stream. At that point, dd will exit with zero bytes read, and the loop will restart it, again and again... Sadly, detecting that is harder to do, since it's still a successful run as far as dd is concerned.

Options there would be to read the data to a temporary file before passing it on, so you can check the size of the file before deciding to continue; or to read the stderr output of dd to get the amount of data copied. (Or to read the data to a shell variable, but that's not 8-bit clean in most shells, zsh being an exception (I think).)

Usually, you should also check the exit status of dd, to be able to break the loop on any errors, but checking for a zero-byte run should also do.

Alternatively, you could open the FIFO in read-write mode, so if the actual writer closes, `dd` or `head` in your loop would end up blocking on itself, so to say. The loop wouldn't exit, but at least it wouldn't end up in a busyloop.

So perhaps something like this:

```
while true; do head -c 65536| redis ... ; done 0<> fifo
```

or to also break the loop if `head` or `redis` fails:

```
set -o pipefail
while head -c 65536 | redis ... ; do true; done 0<> fifo
```

---

Anyway, something like that would likely be better implemented in something other than the shell, e.g. in Perl, or using some existing tool. (like `split`).

Comment: Thank you for clear information.